# Android VPN authentication and encryption

Tags: java, android, vpn

In the Android sample VPN app [ToyVpn](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ToyVpn/index.html) the handshake method says "To build a secured tunnel, we should perform mutual authentication and exchange session keys for encryption."

Can anyone give or point me to some examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, not trivial. You could use SSL mutual authentication (with a client key/certificate) to achieve this. Look at OpenVPN for inspiration. If you don't know what 'mutual authentication' means, don't try to implement this, use a ready solution.

Comment: Good :) My point was, that you shouldn't write this sort of thing for production if you don't understand cryptography. Even if you think you  do, it still might not be a good idea. So read a good security and cryptography introduction book, and check out OpenVPN code. Here's an overview of SSL mutual authentication from Wikipedia  to give you a general idea (that's just one way to do it): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Layer#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake

Comment: @NikolayElenkov how can we pass authentication in PPTP connection . i have purchased a PPTP server and want to connect it with toyvpn but my handshake failed all the time any solution or where to ger ready solution ?